# Geometric proof of $|\frac{e^{j\theta} - a}{1 - ae^{j\theta}}| = 1$

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry, inversive-geometry

This can be proven algebraically,

$$\left|\frac{-a+e^{-j \theta}}{1-a e^{-j \theta}}\right|=\sqrt{\frac{(-a+\cos (-\theta))^2+(\sin (-\theta))^2}{(1-a \cos (-\theta))^2+(a \sin (-\theta))^2}}=\sqrt{\frac{a^2-2 a \cos (\theta)+1}{a^2-2 a \cos (\theta)+1}}=1$$

This is unsatisfying because the problem has a nice geometric meaning. Note that $\left|\frac{-a+e^{-j \theta}}{1-a e^{-j \theta}}\right| = 1 \iff \left|\frac{-a+e^{-j \theta}}{\frac 1 a - e^{-j \theta}}\right| = |a|$.

Geometrically, this is equivalent to proving that the blue length in this diagram is $a$ times larger than the green length.

[image: Diagram of unit circle, with a green line from (1/k, 0) to a point on the circle, and a blue line from that point on the circle to (k,0)]

I know that the $\frac 1 a $ and $a$ points have very useful properties in projective geometry, but I couldn't quite write a proof.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pole_and_polar

Comment: Not a solution, just a thought: Your 1 is not a terribly geometric concept, but if you interpret it as the radius of the circle it becomes more geometric. In [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFr5M.png) I've drawn two similar triangles. $\triangle APB$ is the one you drew, with $A=a,B=\frac1a,P=e^{j\theta}$. $\triangle AOQ$ is similar, with $O=0$ the origin and $Q$ the second point where $BP$ intersects the circle. If you can show these two triangles to be similar, you are done since $\lvert OQ\rvert=1$ and $\lvert OA\rvert=a$ so the ratio blue : green is $a:1$ in both triangles.

Comment: Since [pole and polar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pole_and_polar) is a concept that maps points to lines and vice versa, [circle inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_inversion) might be a better term for describing the relationship between $a$ and $\frac 1a$.

Comment: The proof is straightforward using the cosine rule, if you consider that a geometric proof.